# Conditional E2E tests with Cypress for a payment processor

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

We are using GoPay.com for payments in our app. It runs in two modes, full redirect to their site or iframe based solution to show the payment form inline. The conditions for display either of those is not exactly clear and might vary per a browser and who knows what else.

I need to interact with the payment form in tests to go through with it, but I am struggling how to do that. There is a sandbox environment, so it's ok to do test (free) payments.

Basically, I tried the following, but Cypress is not waiting for that page to load and fails right away.

```
  cy.window().then(win => {
    if (win.location.host.includes('gopay.com')) {
      return win.document.querySelector('.main-body')
    } else {
      return // find form in iframe somehow
    }
  })
```

Also, I am unsure how to tackle the finding that form in the iframe.

Comment: Maybe try and use cy.location() instead of getting the current window? Then you can use cy.get("iframe").then(iframe => { const frameContent = iframe.contents();  });

Comment: Well, but with `cy.location()` I cannot reach the window to run querySelector, or can I? Either way, the problem obviously lies somewhere else since Cypress won't wait for page load before evaluating this.